# Consistent and independence of ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms

My question is very simple but I want to make sure.
when we say the statement is independent of ZFC means, we can not this statement true or false by using only the axioms of ZFC. **Is that right?**

The second thing: when we say that is consistent with ZFC follows from, e.g., **CH** statement true means there is a module ZFC+CH for which the statement is true. **Is that right?**

Basically, I am looking for the easiest way to understand these concepts without going to more complicated definitions.

Comment: For the first question, assuming you meant “we cannot **prove** this statement true or false using only the axioms from ZFC”, it is correct. I can’t understand your second question at all… I assume by “module”, you mean “model”, but even with that correction I cannot follow what you are asking.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, thank you for your comment what does ‘’ it is consistent with ZFC” mean?

Comment: “X is consistent with ZFC” means “ZFC does not prove $\lnot$X”, or equivalently “there is a model of ZFC+X.”

Comment: "Model", not "module". Modules are other things.

Answer (score 1):

Jech describes the relationship between these concepts thusly:

> Let $T$ be a mathematical theory, and let $A$ be an additional axiom. We say that $T+A$ is *consistent relative to $T$* (or that $A$ is *consistent with $T$*) if the following implication holds: if $T$ is consistent, then so is $T+A$. If both $A$ and $\neg A$ are both consistent with $T$, we say that $A$ is *independent* of $T$.
> The question whether $A$ is consistent with $T$ is equivalent to the question whether the negation of $A$ is provable in $T$ (provided $T$ is consistent); this is because $T+A$ is consistent if and only if $\neg A$ is not provable in $T$.
> The way to show that an axiom $A$ is consistent with $ZF$ ($ZFC$) is to use models. For assume that we have a model $\mathfrak{M}$ of $ZF$ such that $\mathfrak{M}\models A$. Then $A$ is consistent with $ZF$: If it were not, then $\neg A$ would be provable in $ZF$, and since $\mathfrak{M}$ is a model of $ZF$, $\mathfrak{M}$ would satisfy $\neg A$. (Here we tacitly use the fact that if $\mathfrak{M}$ is a model of a theory $T$ and $\sigma$ is a sentence provable in $T$, then $\mathfrak{M}$ models $\sigma$.) However, $\mathfrak{M}\models \neg A$ contradicts $\mathfrak{M} \models A$ since $\mathfrak{M} \models \neg A$ iff $\mathfrak{M} \not\models A$.

("Set Theory", 1978 p. 79)

To summarize: yes to your first question, your second question has the right idea but the wording is a little off.